# Google Sheet Clear Button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to clear a spreadsheet I have within Google. I'm using the following code but can't seem to get it to work.I think my code is too long. can anyone simplify it? It's a lot of help for my job.

```
  function ClearCell() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('customer_list');
  sheet.getRange("B34:G34").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H34:J34").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H37:J37").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H40:J40").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H43:J43").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H46:J46").clearContent();'
```

and so on.................

[overview image for the whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvSjI.png)

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the function looks like this:

```
function ClearCell() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('customer_list');
  sheet.getRange("B34:G34").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H34:J34").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H37:J37").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H40:J40").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H43:J43").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("H46:J46").clearContent();
}
```

It looks okay to me.  Is there any more?  What's the and so  on...

Comment: Hi Sir Rubén, the error message is "exceeded execution time. so on means there are 390 lines. Sorry I cannot paste it all

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below.. it worked for me!

```
  var rng = sheet.getRange("H34:J34")
  for(i=0;i<390;i++){
    rng.clearContent()
    rng=rng.offset(3,0)
    Logger.log("Clearing " + rng.getA1Notation())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is massively bloated. You are doing a lot of `getRange().clearContet()` operations. You should avoid writing to the spreadsheet as much as possible. If you cannot clear the values with just 1 range, then instead I would recommend to use

```
dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
arrValues = dataRange.getValues();
```

Then with the 2D array, you simply run a for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < arrValues.length; i++) {
  if (/* How to identify the row you wish to delete */) {
    for (ii = 0; ii < arrValues[i].length; ii++) {
      if (/* Whatever rule defines that the cell needs to be cleared*/)
        arrValues[i][ii] = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have finished up with the array just simply do

```
 dataRange.setValues(arrValues)
```

Obviously, this is just the rough idea. You can write the `for` loops better and of course you need to figure out how to identify which fields you wish to clear